# What is the difference between cv2.waitKey() and cv2.waitKey(0)?

Tags: python, opencv

I have found a lot of questions around about what is `cv2.waitKey()` used for, about the difference between `cv2.waitKey(0)` and `cv2.waitKey(1)`, etc., the answers to which can be found in many OpenCV documentations. Yet, I have not found any documentation or people asking about the **difference between `cv2.waitKey(0)` and `cv2.waitKey()`**. Both seem to have the same effect, namely waiting for a keypress before the image window is closed. Yet, In dozens of codes that I have seen, they all use `cv2.waitKey(0)`. For example:

```
cv2.imshow("my_image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

So, is there a particular reason for that or is `0` just useless?

(My opencv-python version is 4.9.0.80.)

Comment: It is documented, just non-verbally (but it's consistent throughout the OpenCV docs): The C++ signature `int cv::waitKey(int delay = 0)` tells you that `delay` is an optional argument with a default value of 0. The Python signature `cv.waitKey([, delay]) -> retval` also tells you that `delay` is optional (the square brackets enclosing it). The default value is not repeated for the Python signature, since the code is auto-generated from the C++ API. Then it's just about understanding the language features, and that's out of scope of library documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

`waitKey()`'s first argument's default is 0. If you call the function without arguments, the default argument is used.

Nothing in C++ or Python *forbids* you from passing values equal to the defaults. It is not an error and not a problem. It is a matter of style.

Comment: OK, I accept that. Thanks.